# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server in django channels echo server

Tags: django, django-channels, channel

I wrote an echo server with Django Channels, which I will give you the link

[channels_echo_server](https://github.com/mehdish9197/echo_server.git)

When I try to connect to Echo Server, I get this error in the console

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/

Socket closed unexpectedly
`

and In terminal-->not found:/ws/

I get the same error in the Chrome browser

I uninstalled and reinstalled Channels and even the Django project several times

But it didn't work

where is the problem from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

I put an `as_asgi()` in the routing.py (echo app) after the consumer class and it worked.

In echo/routing.py:

```
path('ws/',consumers.EchoConsumer.as_asgi())
```